# Problems Integrating Phonegap Barcode Scanner for Android

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I am trying to get this example project to work: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/barcode-scanner-example-projects.html

I have imported both the projects and made the library project a library etc and i have it running but when i run it and click the scan button i get:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'exec' at file://android_asset/www/cordova.js:863`

I have changed the target version to 17 (the latest) which allowed me to run it but i cannot seem to get it to work am i missing something?

I would like to run this on my Google Nexus 4 if this info helps.
Here is a zip of all the code i am using: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1099165/bc-code.zip
Also i am using Eclipse to run this (ADT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Noogen's answer it got me thinking if Cordova needed to be updated so i grabbed the latest phonegap files and replaced the cordova.js file and the 2.8.1 jar file and then did a clean and build - it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Because your barcodescanner.js is using old API call.  There is no longer cordova.exec.  You need to use the latest barcodescanner.js:  https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.2.0/assets/www/barcodescanner.js

Comment: i already had the latest barcodescanner.js the error relates to the cordova.js file